# Save mp3 in subdirectory of raw folder in Android. I have over 200 sounds

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, android-resources

I can save .mp3 files in the raw folder, access them by id then play them using a media player

```
MediaPlayer.create( getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound1 )
```

However my app has 200+ sounds so I want to organise them into folders. I have created subdirectories in the raw folder, but I can't access them by ID.

This does not work

```
MediaPlayer.create( getApplicationContext(), R.raw.group1.sound1 )
```

How should I separate different types of sound so that my app is maintainable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have subdirectories of resource directories. Use a naming convention instead.

So, instead of trying to have `res/raw/group1/sound1.mp3`, use `res/raw/group1_sound1.mp3`, and request `R.raw.group1_sound1`.